# Letter and word spacing decreases in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I checked the font menu and everything is default. Whenever I open a document, all letters are closer to each other than they should be and all words are farther than they should be. Even the documents look normal in other computers are looks this way in my comptuer.

I added an image for showing the problem. First part is what it should be and second part is what I get.

[image: letter spacing problem]

What could e the problem? I also checked options page but I couldn't find something related.

Comment: Is it the same even if you choose a different printer in file-print?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the character spacing and kerning settings are ok.

1. Select the text
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to open the **Font** dialog box
3. On the **Advanced** tab ensure the settings, especially for **Scale** and **Spacing** are set to default as follows:

[image: 1]

Comment: This is the first thing I checked but eveything is exactly same with yours.

Comment: Are you sure the font(s) used in the document are present on your PC?

Comment: Yes, it is Times New Roman and I am using Win7. I also checked fonts folder to verify.